# Rails: How can I integrate Bootstrap-table & X-editable with Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm using the following project:
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/

That I integrated using this gem: https://github.com/bjevanchiu/bootstrap-table-rails

It works well but now I'd like to leverage the editable extension provided by the bootstrap-table library

Here is my html:

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="comments" data-editable="true">Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <%= render @tables %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

The rendering works well, I can click on the elements like here: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html

The thing is, my Active Records are not updated after I validate a change. It seems that no "PUT" request happens... (in fact, nothing happens).

I'm new to Rails so I may be missing something obvious... It seems there is a `data-url` option for the `<table>` tag but I'm not sure if and how I should use it.

Thanks!